# Meteor: access template helpers inside an each statement

Tags: html, meteor, spacebars

So if I have a template and I have some helpers defined for that template, I can use them normally within the template, but if I try to use them inside an `{{#each whatever}}` it gives me an error. See this example:

```
 {{#unless pollIsOpenHelper}}
  <p>This poll closed on {{formatDate time_poll_closed}}.</p>
{{/unless}}

<table>
  {{ #each indexedArray choices }}
    <tr>
      <td><span class="votes">{{ votes }}</span></td>
      <td><span class="text">{{ text }}</span></td>
      <td><a href="#" class="vote" data-id="{{ _index }}"><button>Vote for this option</button></a></td>
    </tr>

    {{#unless pollIsOpenHelper}}
      <p>CLOSED.</p>
    {{/unless}}

  {{ /each }}
</table>
```

The above helper inside the `{{#unless}}` works perfectly, only displays the message if the poll is closed. However, if I try to do the same to display a message inside the `{{#each}}` below, the helper does not work and always shows me message. The console gives me: `Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'poll_is_open' of undefined`

EDIT: This is the helper code:

```
  Template.poll.helpers({

    pollIsOpenHelper: function() {
      var poll_is_open = Polls.findOne({_id: this._id}).poll_is_open;

      return poll_is_open;
    },

  });
```

Comment: The [context changes](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/a-guide-to-meteor-templates-data-contexts/) inside of an `#each`. A precise answer can't be given without the helper code.

Comment: I've added the helper code

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is caused by the data context changing inside of your `each` loop as others have stated.  Which is causing `this._id` to be something other than what you expect.

Assuming you're on a version of Meteor `1.2.x+`, you can get around this issue by using the *new* [`{{#each thing in iterable}}`](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/spacebars/README.md#each) spacebars construct which does not override the data context.

You would use it as follows:

```
{{#each array in indexedArray choices}} 
  //doStuff
{{/each}}
```

If you're not on a version of Meteor `1.2.x+`, you can modify your helper to take a param as shown below:

```
Template.poll.helpers({
  pollIsOpenHelper: function(poll) {
    var poll_is_open = Polls.findOne({_id: poll._id}).poll_is_open;
    return poll_is_open;
  },
});
```

Which would be called in your template as: `{{#unless pollIsOpenHelper this}}` outside of your `#each` block or `{{#unless pollIsOpenHelper ../}}` inside of your `#each block`

Answer (score 0):

You can call `Template.instance()` from inside the each to get your instance and the helpers.

Comment: Could you explain a little more?